# Problem with creating a new user in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I try to create a new user

```
CREATE USER mike@ourcorp.com IDENTIFIED BY ',~UU6eW6nc9RS'
```

but I get an error message `Query failed: Invalid query.`

I got the same result for

```
CREATE USER 'mike@ourcorp.com' IDENTIFIED BY ',~UU6eW6nc9RS'
```

[image]